# Restart mysqld with a command line parameter on ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, upstart

Getting my hands dirty with a MySql slave setup, I ran into a puzzling question: how do I pass any of the myriad options to mysqld (--skip-slave-start in this particular case) when I am restarting it and it is installed as an Upstart job?

I can think of many ways to hack it, but I feel I must be missing something obvious.

TIA,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider specifying `skip-slave-start` in the cnf instead.  Typically, flags are specified in the init script, which would be located in `/etc/init.d`.

Comment: I agree with Warner. 
Set the options in the config file. If you do want to pass options to mysqld in the init script the file you need is actually /etc/init/mysql.conf and the options get added to line 27 on a standard 10.04 install.

You can start mysqld from the command line without using init at all but it is not a good solution for production use.

Comment: Right, both editing the cnf and starting it on the command line were in fact my "hack it" solutions. I probably should have been more specific - the option I want to pass to mysqld is not permanent, it's only a one-time option. Mysqld is already running, I just need to temporarily restart it with this option while I perform some administration (setup as a slave), after that I'd restart it again in production mode, i.e. without the option.

Again it's not a blocker or anything, I'm just puzzled about the lack of this feature.

Comment: Why would you restart when you can just `stop slave;`?  `skip-slave-start` is to prevent it upon startup.

Comment: Warner, that is correct. I was getting some errors after doing this via stop slave; and I thought they were caused by the threads having started then stopped, so I went off this tangent, but the same errors still happen. Thanks!